# Exporting class using ES6 syntax fails in Facebook Flow

Tags: javascript, facebook, ecmascript-6

I want to add Flow type annotations to a class containing a function defined in ES6 style, below is analyzed correctly:

```
/* @flow */
class Product {
  items: Array<string>;

  addItem = (item:string) => {
    this.items.push(item)
  };
}
```

If I add `export default` to export the Product class, I get:

```
class property `addItem` missing type annotation.
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had an old version of Flow installed globally at 0.23.0, which was incompatible.  Upgrading to flow 0.30.0 fixed the issue.